# Can I use an Iterator inside another Iterator?

Tags: java, iterator

I have a HashTable (I implemented the structure) that implements linked lists to treat collisions (I also implemented the lists).

Both of them have Iterators.

I want to use a Table as a structure for a class and want to iterate over each item in it.

Can I implement an Iterator that iterates first over each HashTable position and then over each LinkedList node using those iterators? How?

Ex.:

```
--> HashPos1
  --> List1Pos1
  --> List1Pos2
  --> List1Pos3
--> HashPos2
  --> List2Pos1
  --> List2Pos2
  --> List2Pos3
--> HashPos3
  --> List3Pos1
  --> List3Pos2
  --> List3Pos3
```

Code:

```
public Iterator<Node> iterator() {
    private List LocalList = this.Table.getFirst();
    private Table LocalTable = this.Table;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (LocalList.hasNext() && LocalTable.pos < LocalTable.tam) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Node next() {
        if (list.hasNext()) {
            return list.next();
        } else if (table.hasNext() {
            list = table.next();
            // and so on...
        }

    }
}
```

Or something of the kind.

Comment: Can you ident your code please ?

Comment: Generally nesting iterators is OK so long as you're not modifying either AND you are being careful - please read the "common mistake" in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html  .   Today, for-loops are SO much nicer and less error-prone.